# JavaScript click event keeps adding previously clicked items to list

Tags: javascript, events, click

Please excuse my spaghetti code. I'm trying to learn.

When I click on the `add food` button, it adds a food item to the nutrition list. However, when I choose another food and add that, the previous food item is added along with the current chosen food. Again, if I continue the process, all of the previously added items are added, including the current item. So the result is a list of previously added food and it's terrible. It seems that whenever I click on a food item, all the previously clicked items are being "held" or still referenced somehow. I don't understand why this is happening.

I need to make it so that only one food item is added at a time. I've researched a lot but can't find solutions similar to my problem.

Here is my code. I've left comments around the problem area.

JavaScript:

```
const callApi = (url) => {
   fetch(url).then(function(response) {
   return response.json();
})
.then(function (data) {
  if (data.hits.length > 0) {
   data.hits.forEach((foodItem) => {
   makeFoodInstance(foodItem);
});
    } else {
   displayResults.innerHTML = "No results match this search."
    }
  });
}

const makeFoodInstance = (f) => {
  let food = new Food(f.fields.item_id, f.fields.item_name);
  food.carbohydrates(f.fields.nf_dietary_fiber, f.fields.nf_sugars, 
    f.fields.nf_total_carbohydrate);
  food.fats(f.fields.nf_saturated_fat, f.fields.nf_polyunsaturated_fat, 
  f.fields.nf_monounsaturated_fat, f.fields.nf_trans_fatty_acid, 
  f.fields.nf_total_fat);
  food.minerals(f.fields.nf_calcium_dv, f.fields.nf_sodium, 
  f.fields.nf_iron_dv);
  food.vitamins(f.fields.nf_vitamin_a_dv, f.fields.nf_vitamin_c_dv);
  food.protein(f.fields.nf_protein);
  food.calories(f.fields.nf_calories, f.fields.nf_calories_from_fat);
  food.water(f.fields.nf_water_grams);
  food.servings(f.fields.nf_servings_per_container, 
  f.fields.nf_serving_size_qty, f.fields.nf_serving_size_unit);
  displayResults.children[0].innerHTML = '';
  resultsList.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<li class="results-list-
   item">${food.name}</li>`);
   getNutrition(food);
}


const getNutrition = (nutrition) => {
  let foodResultItem = document.querySelector('.results-list-item');
  let nutritionListItem =
      `<li class="nutrition-list-item">
        <p>${nutrition.name}</p>
        <p>Sugars ${nutrition.sugars}</p>
        <p>Total Carbohydrates ${nutrition.total_carbs}</p>
        <p>Saturated Fat ${nutrition.satured}</p>
        <p>Polyunsaturated Fat ${nutrition.polyunsaturated}</p>
        <p>Monounsaturated Fat ${nutrition.monounsaturated}</p>
        <p>Trans Fat ${nutrition.trans}</p>
        <p>Total Fat ${nutrition.total_fat}</p>
        </li>
      `;

    /* 
       this is where the problem is starting (i think)
       passing the nutrition variable to storeFood()
    */
  foodResultItem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    nutritionList.innerHTML = '';
    nutritionList.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', nutritionListItem);
    storeFood(nutrition);
  }, false);
}

const storeFood = (f) => {
  addFood.addEventListener('click', (a) => {
    if (localStorage) {
      localStorage.setItem(f.id, f.name.toString());
      userAddedFood.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<li class="selected-
food-item">${f.name}</li>`);
     } else {
      userAddedFood.append('Sorry, storage is full');
    }
  }, false);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <section class="search">
    <h1>Health Tracker</h1>
    <input type="text" id="search-bar">
    <input type="submit" value="search" id="search-btn">
  </section>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <section class="results">
    <h3>Search results will display here</h3>
    <ul id="results-list"></ul>
  </section>
  <section class="nutrition-results">
    <h3>Nutrition Facts</h3>
    <ul id="nutrition-list"></ul>
    <input type="button" value="add-food" id="add-food-button">
  </section>
   <section class="selected-food">
     <h3>Foods you've eaten today</h3>
     <ul class="users-food-result"></ul>
  </section>
  <section class="user-nutrition-facts">
    <h3>Your daily nutrition totals</h3>
    <div class="users-nutrition-totals"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include the html that is generated by the bulk of this code so we can see the html and event handlers in action?

Comment: I've included it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like every time a `foodResultItem` gets clicked, you call `storeFood()` passing in the current nutrition item. `storeFood` itself creates a click handler on `addFood` that adds that specific food item to the list. These click handlers for each specific food stick around on the `addFood` element, even when you create new ones by clicking on a different `foodResultItem`. So when you click the `addFood` button, ALL of the event handlers you have added to it run, giving you the unwanted results.

Comment: Yes, this is something I suspected and it turns out to be the case. After more investigating, I've come up with this ```addbutton.onclick = function() { //add selected food to nutrition view }```, and it's working fine now. Thank you very much for helping me! Much appreciated.